# Issue with unix script to display & delete records one by one

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm stuck with one of my requirements. I've to write a small unix script to delete some file from my filesystem. 
It should go into /myDir directory and select all the subdirectories and sub-subdirectories with size in GB. 
And then go one by one into these directories using a for loop and then display & delete the file older than 30th November 2014 under them using another for loop.

I've written a small script(to just display the possibilities) but it is displaying wrong records under myDir, not the one I want.
It is also not displaying anything using echo command in the script. Probably I'm using awk command in a wrong way.

Here is my script:

```
for dir in `du -kh * |grep 'G' |awk '{print $2}'`; do     
    cd /myDir/$dir
    for file in `ls -al blk_* | awk '$6 == "Nov" && $7 <= 30 {print $9}'`; do
        echo "$file";
    done
done
```

Any help would be of great help.

Comment: you should not parse output of ls command.

Comment: almas shaikh Sorry I couldnt understand. Could you please let me know wgat changes should be done?  Thanks.

Comment: You want to delete files older than 30th November of what year? Otherwise, there's a simple solution: delete all the files; they're all older than a certain November 30th.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf should be of 2014. Though my current script has been written for only November month..needs a lot of corrections.

Comment: Why do you want to perform these loops manually? it's: slow, ridiculous, dangerous and broken. Here's a `find` solution: `find -type f \! -newermt '2014-11-30' -delete`.

Answer (score 4):

Parsing `ls` is never the way to go. I think that `find` is more suited to this task:

```
touch -d 2014-11-30 dummy
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'blk_*' \! -newer dummy -delete 
rm dummy
```

This creates a dummy file, with a timestamp of 30th November, 2014. It searches in the current directory for any files beginning with `blk_` that are older than the dummy file and removes them. I assume that the `-a` argument to `ls` in your attempt was just copied from elsewhere, as it is not serving any useful purpose.

Depending on your version of `find` you may alternatively be able to do the comparison directly, using the `-newermt` switch to specify the date as suggested by [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf):

```
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'blk_*' \! -newermt '2014-11-30' -delete
```

You can put these commands inside your outer loop or if you prefer, replace the entire script and change `-maxdepth` to 2 (and perhaps also add a `-mindepth` if there are other files that you want to avoid matching in `mydir`). `find` also allows you to match files greater than a certain size, so you could add that in if you wanted.

Comment: Or use `\! -newermt '2014-11-30'` (as in my comment to the OP). It's not POSIX but neither is `-maxdepth`. `:)`.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't it be `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks for the info, edited. I was more thinking that this would be a replacement for the inner loop but I guess the whole thing could be done in one go.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with find like this

**To see all files that suit your conditions**

```
find . -type f -size +1G  -newermt "2014-11-01" ! -newermt "2014-11-30" -ls
```

..

```
-type f find all files 
-size +1G that has a size of 1G or more
-newermt "2014-11-01" ! -newermt "2014-11-30" the files must be in the month of november 2014
-ls put them in ls format
```

**To delete all files the command line above can be modified to read**

```
   find . -type f -size +1G  -newermt "2014-11-01" ! -newermt "2014-11-30" -exec sh -c 'echo deleting {};rm -f  "{}"' \;
```

this piece below from the command line above will delete files and display filename being deleted

```
-exec sh -c 'echo deleting {};rm -f  "{}"' \; this will remove all files and display a message of the file being deleted.
```

Comment: `{}` is not meant to be used that way. It's dangerous and broken. Really, don't. Instead: `-exec sh -c 'echo "deleting $0";rm -f  "$0"' '{}' \;`. Or just use `-printf 'deleting %p\n' -delete` (it's not POSIX but you're using lots of non-POSIX stuff anyways).